# Connecting Galaxy S3 to DisplayPort via MHL HDTV Adaptor

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, hdmi, external-display

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3, and I just bought the [Samsung HDTV Adapter](http://www.grosbill.com/4-samsung_adaptateur_micro_usb_vers_hdmi_11_pins_pour_samsung_galaxy_s3-167046-mobilite_pda-accessoire_divers_pour_telephone) (MHL to HDMI). However, my Dell U2412M monitor only has VGA, DVI or DisplayPort. So I also bought an [HDMI to displayPort](http://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B0017K6BDW/ref=oh_details_o02_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) converter cable. Alas, the connection doesn't work.

I know that everything is properly connected. The Samsung MHL is properly connected to both the phone and the (official Samsung) charger. The HDMI cable goes from there to the displayPort to HDMI (female) adapter, which in turn is properly fitted to the monitor. Then, I switch the input on the monitor to DisplayPort, and sadly my monitor goes to power save mode.

Is there anything I can do to make this configuration work? If not, have you got any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cable is not going to work.  That adapter will only allow you to go from a (dual-mode) Displayport source to an HDMI input, not the other way around like you're trying to use it.

To go from an HDMI source to a Displayport input, you need an active converter, such as [this Startech unit](http://ca.startech.com/AV/Converters/Video/HDMI-or-DVI-to-DisplayPort-Active-Converter~HDMI2DP), not merely an adapter, as Displayport uses a fundamentally different means of data transmission (It's a packetized connection like USB, not just a digital stream) than HDMI or DVI.

Comment: Ouch! Very expensive... OK, so that explains why my set didn't work. Thanks very much for your answer. I wish I could Upvote you right now but that will have to wait till I get enough rep.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to consider:

- Make sure the HDTV adapter is connected to a USB power such as the wall or a PC (the USB from the TVs don't give enough power)
- Have you tried the HDMI to display port adapter with another HDMI output such as your laptop or PC? maybe this is faulty
- Try using an HDMI to DVI adaptor
- Try another HDMI monitor to ensure its not your monitor

Comment: Thanks, all good advice. 1. All connected properly. 2. Not yet but I will 3. don't have one 4. I tried on another monitor, and it works.

Comment: so are you saying that you tried the same configuration on an HDMI monitor and it worked? that means its the HDMI to display port adaptor that is not working (either faulty or just not compatible with your monitor input or hdmi output)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. However on the second part of your interpretation I would add that it is also possible that  MHL or something in the S3 configuration makes it unable to work through an HDMI to DisplayPort adapter. Either way, the Samsun MHL adapter I bought does work when directly connected to an HDMI monitor. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 1):

Another U2412M user here

Since DisplayPort has been ruled out, DVI is supposed to be good alternative since it's "electrically compatible" with HDMI.

Unfortunately, that's not the case for Android device + U2412M :(

I have personally tested MicroHDMI - DVI (Xperia Pro MK16) and MHL - DVI cable (HTC One M7) with this monitor, none of those combinations appear to work. The monitor simply reverts to sleep mode within 5 minutes.

Edit: MHL works only in 640x480 resolution, and I must pull the power from the monitor USB hub, previously I only tried plugging the MHL usb plug to wall charger with no success.

I have also tested different cables, and all of them works fine when connected to a laptop.

In the end I simply get (micro) HDMI to VGA adapter and finally the U2412M able to mirror my phone display. Make sure you get the one with microUSB port, otherwise your phone battery will be drained fast.

I assume MHL to VGA adaptor should also works.